# Rails select and submitting a 2nd value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using the select method in my erb here:

```
<%= select(:user_action, :user_id, @basic_users.map {|v| [ v['first_name'] + ' ' + v['last_name'], v['id'] ] }) %>
```

...and this works great. The select box shows me the users name, and submits the id just like I want. However, I have another field in my model for the user_name that I would also like to save. Any ideas on how I might do this? Hidden field maybe? The idea is that my UI looks the same...the user would choose based on the concatenated first/last name, but on submission the id is saved to the user_id field, but the name would also be saved to the user_name field.

In my mind I'd like to add something like...

```
<%= hidden_field :user_action, :user_name, value: v['first_name'] %>
```

..but for obvious reasons this doesn't work...it doesn't know what v is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use javascript to update the hidden field value when you make the selection or you can handle it in your controller by looking up the user with the id you submitted.

Comment: You are probably right...doing something in the controller is based on the id is probably the way to go. Thanks@